# Word Viewer Service randomly fails to open documents

Tags: office-web-apps

I am able to open documents using word viewer service. however I get a lot of complains from users that they are not able to open word documents with unexpected error.

in my ULS logs there are 100s of instances of this very same exception.

Note that I am running the word viewer service application with an account which is local admin on all WFE and SA machines.

I have verified that `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Office Server\14.0` key has permission of `Full Control` to `adminsitrators`, `wss_wpg`, `wss_wpg_adm`, `iis_susrs`, the domain account running farm, domain account running service applications.

```
Unexpected exception System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Office.Web.Environment.Sharepoint.ConversionServiceApplication' 
threw an exception. 
---> System.Security.SecurityException: Requested registry access is not allowed.
at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenSubKey(String name, Boolean writable) 
at Microsoft.Office.Web.Environment.Sharepoint.ConversionServiceApplication..cctor()
```

The Zone of the assembly that failed was:

```
MyComputer --- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers._RunClassConstructor(IntPtr type) 
at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) 
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAutoSerializingObject.GetInstanceFromType(Type type, String typename) 
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedObject.GetInstance(XmlNode xml, Guid classId, Boolean bResolveMissingTypes) 
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.GetObject(Guid id, Guid parentId, Guid type, String name, SPObjectStatus status, Byte[] versionBuffer, String xml) 
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.FetchObject(Guid id) 
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.GetObject(Guid id, Boolean checkInMemoryCache, Boolean checkFileSystemCache) 
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPConnectedServiceApplication.get_ApplicationAddresses() 
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPServiceLoadBalancer.<get_EndpointAddresses>d__0.MoveNext() at Microsoft.Office.Web.Environment.Sharepoint.SharepointServiceLoadBalancer.EnsureInitialization() 
at Microsoft.Office.Web.Environment.Sharepoint.SharepointServiceLoadBalancer.GetLoadBalancedUri(String id) 
at Microsoft.Office.Web.Environment.Sharepoint.SharepointServiceLoadBalancer.GetLoadBalancedUri(BaseDocument doc) 
at Microsoft.Office.Web.Conversion.Viewing.RequestDispatcher.DispatchRequest(RenderRequest request, ServiceLoadBalancer balancer, Int32 retryCount) 
at Microsoft.Office.Web.Conversion.Viewing.RequestDispatcher.BeginProcessRequest(RenderRequest request, ServiceLoadBalancer balancer, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) 
at Microsoft.Office.Web.Conversion.Viewing.Client.DocumentViewer.BeginConvertDocument(RenderRequest request, ServiceLoadBalancer balancer, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) 
at Microsoft.Office.Web.Conversion.Viewing.Client.Librarian.DispatchRenderRequest(LibrarianGetItemInfo info) 
at Microsoft.Office.Web.Conversion.Viewing.Client.Librarian.OnReceivedStoredData(IAsyncResult ar) StackTrace:   
at Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.Log.ShipAssertTag(UInt32 tag, Category category, Boolean condition, String formatString, Object[] data) 
at Microsoft.Office.Web.Conversion.Viewing.Client.Librarian.OnReceivedStoredData(IAsyncResult ar) 
at Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.AsyncResult`1.SetCompleted(T result, Exception e, Boolean completedSynchronously) 
at Microsoft.Office.Web.Conversion.Viewing.Client.ViewItemStore.SetCompleted(ItemRetrievalInfo info, ItemRetrievalStatus status) 
at Microsoft.Office.Web.Conversion.Viewing.Client.ViewItemStore.OnReceivedDocumentInfoFromMainCache(IAsyncResult ar) 
at Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.AsyncResult`1.SetCompleted(T result, Exception e, Boolean completedSynchronously) 
at Microsoft.Office.Web.Conversion.Storage.DocumentInfoCache.BeginRefreshDocumentInfo(BaseDocument baseDoc, OutputFormat outputFormat, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) 
at Microsoft.Office.Web.Conversion.Viewing.Client.ViewItemStore.ReadMainCache(ItemRetrievalInfo info) 
at Microsoft.Office.Web.Conversion.Viewing.Client.ViewItemStore.BeginGetItem(BaseDocument baseDoc, ViewItem item, ServiceLoadBalancer balancer, Stream outputStream, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) 
at Microsoft.Office.Web.Conversion.Viewing.Client.Librarian.BeginGetItem(BaseUser user, BaseDocument baseDoc, ViewItem item, ServiceLoadBalancer balancer, Stream outputStream, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) 
at Microsoft.Office.Web.Conversion.Viewing.DocDataHandlerAsync.StartInternal() 
at Microsoft.Office.Web.Conversion.Viewing.DocDataHandlerAsync.Start() 
at Microsoft.Office.Web.Conversion.Viewing.DocDataHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) 
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() 
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) 
at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error) 
at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb) 
at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) 
at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags) 
at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags) 
at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags) 
at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
```

Comment: Thing to note about this error is that when two users access the same document. One can open the document successfully in browser... while the other gets this error.

So once again, this error is very intermittent and its hard to say when it will occur.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following steps it will resolve your problem.

In "Central Admin SharePoint" go to "Security" and "Configure Service accounts"

Chose Service Pool Application"SharePoint Web Services Default" and select a user who has enough privilege. I think the user should have dbcreator privilege on DB Instance SQL Server 2008. In my case i chose a SharePoint Farm Administrator user. Then press "OK"

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/officeitproprevious/thread/656b0744-c41e-4fb8-a289-1f6560c80148